# add worker node and rebalance distributed shards problem with PostgreSQL + Citus

Tags: postgresql, citus

The cluster had 1 coordinator and 6 worker nodes. (environment: PostgreSQL 15 + Citus 11.1)

We want to add more worker nodes to it, so we executed
`SELECT * from citus_add_node('node-name', 5432);`
and
`SELECT rebalance_table_shards('table_name');` to got the messages as below:

`ERROR:  connection to the remote node 10.128.0.37:5432 failed with the following error: ERROR:  subscription "citus_shard_move_subscription_10" does not exist`

We have no way to solve it.

Hope somebody can help out. Thanks a lot!

We have tried Google and Citus official doc, but these is no solution for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are another error happened that in turn triggered this one, but this original error is masked by this follow up error. By looking at the logs on 10.128.0.37 you should be able to find out what the original error was.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change configuration postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level = logical
max_replication_slots = 5 # has to be > 0
max_wal_senders = 5       # has to be > 0
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/develop/migration_data_big.html?highlight=logical#enable-logical-replication)